# how to play an audio file from pressing the volume up key

Tags: javascript, button, audio

I am working on a costume and have a camera shutter button that just acts as if it is pressing the volume up button through Bluetooth, now I want to make it play an audio file is this possible? the best I could find is this :

```
var keyDownHandler = function(evt) {
    if (evt.key === 'VolumeDown') {
      var audio = new Audio('phoenix-objection_1');
    audio.play();
    } else if (evt.key === 'VolumeUp') {
      var audio = new Audio('phoenix-objection_1');
      audio.play();
    }
    evt.preventDefault(); // to stop system app from processing keydown event
  };
  
  window.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandler);`
```

but it isn't working when I try with the space key it works perfectly fine can anyone please help me?

now It won't work with any key at all. can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I found a way around it and it is all good however if possible can someone help.